# How to remove the value not key from the associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to remove the value not key from the associative array?

For example:

```
$a = array(0=>yh, 1=>uy,2=>rf);
```

If remove the value of `uy` then o/p:

```
$a = array(0=>yh,1=>rf,2=>0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How are you trying to remove the value of `uy` from the array?

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to remove, from the original array, the key/value pair associated with the value 'uy' then perhaps something like this?

```
$a=array(0=>'yh',1=>'uy',2=>'rf');
array_splice( $a, array_search('uy',$a), 1 );
$a[]=0;
print_r($a);
```